# How to display the full error messages in VScode?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, visual-studio-code, clang

I've got a problem that's bothering me for a long time. I use VScode on macOS with standart clang compiller. Almost all error messages produced by the "gcc" are cut, and don't help me at all. I do not know is it a VScode thing or my compilling settings are wrong. Also, if someone could say why just using "usr/bin/clang++" in command parameter is not working, it'll be excellent...

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqZWm.png)
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjTOl.png)

Comment: Passing "-fmessage-length=0" solved the issue. Also the working clang path lacks slash at the start, so it should be "/usr/bin/clang++" instead of "usr/bin/clang++".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem matcher of the task shows only the first line of error messages. GCC and Clang wrap error messages on multiple lines resulting truncated errors in the VSCode "Problems" panel and tooltips.

Pass the option `-fmessage-length=0` to the compiler to direct it to not wrap lines. Modify "args" in your config.

```
"args": [
  "-fmessage-length=0",
  "-Wall",
  "-Wextra",
  "-std=c++17",
  "-g",
  "${fileDirname}/**.cpp",
  "-o",
  "${fileDirname}"/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
],
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what it means that error messages "are cut", does that mean they are deleted? It looks like from your picture that they are still showing. If you are getting error messages that you fixed, sometimes another build is required for phantom errors to go away.

Addressing the second part, if you moved the bin directory from XcodeDefault.XcodeToolChain/ straight to the usr/ directory, then you could set the command to

> "command": "usr/bin/clang++"

I doubt that clang installed directly to your user folder, however, and it is probably not good practice to move it there since other programs and tasks may still depend on the old location.

Comment: Look at the picture carefully. The sentences of the many error messages are not complete.

Comment: @S.M. Maybe it is because the environment language is different than system language and characters for English are cut from the final message?